# Efficient way for parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry people, a simple question but my concern here is performance implications (javascript):
I have a JSON query result:

> [{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]

In order to prepare it to another query, I need to manipulate it to the following:

> ['a', 'b']

What will be the most efficient way of doing so?
Is it through native JSON libraries or with simple JSON/string parsing?

Thanks

Comment: Valid JSON would be `[{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}]`.

Comment: Are you only going to have 2 objects in an array, or is that just a sample?

Comment: Do you actually have a string, or a JavaScript object? Your first string is not valid JSON, as noted above. You should modify whatever service is providing the result to provide valid JSON instead of "almost-JSON".

Comment: Chrome seems to parse it fine, see the JSFiddle I posted.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/native-vs-array-js-vs-underscore/37

Comment: @TomHart Your code defines a JavaScript literal, and does not parse a JSON string. The grammar for JavaScript object literals is (with minor expections) a *superset* of the JSON grammar. It's not clear if the OP has a **string** being returned by some service (e.g., an HTTP response), or an **object** in a JavaScript environment. Which one it is changes the nature of the answer substantially.

Comment: @Andy:Just an example, most likely hundreds or thousands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var j = [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}];
var k = [];

j.forEach(function (value) {
    k.push(value.name);
});

console.log(k); // Outputs ["a", "b"]
```

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var j = [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}];

var k = j.map(function(v) {

    return v.name;
});

console.log(k); // Outputs ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one option you could do

Simply loop of the JSON array, and add each `name` item to a new array.

```
var original = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];
var newArr = [];

var total = original.length;
for(var i = 0;i < total;i++){
    newArr.push(original[i].name);   
}

console.log(newArr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/satLzvhg/

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at some of those performance tests I'd be happy to just use `map` as it seems to come out on top, even over the native `for-loop` in many cases. It very much depends on the browser afaik. Looks like the libraries like underscore and lodash come out poorly compared to native `for-loop` and `map`.

If you're actually using a JS object and not a string of JSON:

```
var arr = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];

var out = arr.map(function (el) {
  return el.name;
});
```

If that's a string of JSON but you mistyped the question:

```
var json = '[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}]';

var out = JSON.parse(json).map(function (el) {
  return el.name;
});
```